# How an Activity is killed by Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

As we know *Android* would kill a paused *Activity* in some conditions. And there is a FIFO back stack of *Activities*.

My questions are as follows:

1. How Android kills an *Activity* without pulling it from the back stack (it might affect the top active *Activity*)
2. After killing it, what things are released from this *Activity*? And can I still get this *Activity*'s instance?

Comment: From my experience android can throw out any non foregroud app/activity without calling the the `onDestroy` method when memory is needed so even static variables are lost. You should use `onPause` to save all state that is neccessary when app is restarted. If you add a "why you ask" to your question we might help more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Android* [does not kill *Activities* "separately"](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html), it kills the whole app process with all *Activities*.

The only way to get an *Activity* killed by the system is to set *Don't keep Activities* flag in device's Developer Options. However this option is just for development, not for applications in release.

Comment: From my experience, when we jump from Activity A to Activity B, then Activity A is on PAUSED or STOPED status, now the top activity is B. Then in some conditions, system will kill Activity A. I want to know how does system kill the A

Comment: In android website: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle    it said that A paused activity is completely alive, but can be killed by the system in extreme low memory situations.

Comment: This isn't 100% true. There are some cases where Android will kill individual activities. An example is "orientation change". In this case, Android kills the current (topmost `Activity` (by calling `onPause(), onStop()` and `onDestroy()` and then creates a new instance of the `Activity` to handle the orientation change.

Comment: @Onik have you actually tried this? The order of my statements is correct, and your "corrected" order is wrong.

Comment: @David Wasser, correct. I actually "corrected" the order for starting a new instance of already running _Activity_. Anyways, _Activity_'s lifecycle calls invoked within orientation change is a kind of "normal" _Activity_ instance termination, not "killing" .

Answer (score 1):

Activity can't be killed but Os can kill the whole application. In this case you can try `finish()`/`finishActivity()`/`context.finish()` to finish the activity. While you finish an activity backpress will not return to the previous activity.

Comment: Any DOCs to demonstrate that?

Comment: You can read the Android source code. Or you can just see what happens yourself (empirical evidence). Look at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle and search for "kill the process". Also read the section on "cached processes"

Answer (score 1):

System can't kill activity, it can call the whole app.

And when it kills the whole app, it doesn't call any method from activity (onStop(), onDestroy(), etc)

Finally, you can't get activity instance.